# Javascript smooth scrolling with fixed navbar offset

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I found this javascript code for smooth scrolling

```
window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
var scrollContainer = target;
do { //find scroll container
    scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
    if (!scrollContainer) return;
    scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
} while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

var targetY = 0;
do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
    if (target == scrollContainer) break;
    targetY += target.offsetTop;
} while (target = target.offsetParent);

scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
    i++; if (i > 30) return;
    c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
    setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
}
// start scrolling
scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
```

}

and made simple [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjSfP/96/).

As you can see it is scrolling to the red section but it doesn't exclude the height of the navbar. Start of red section goes all up to the top of the page, under navbar.

How to add offset to this script so the red section stops when hit navbar? The padding is not an option, I already tried that and it doesn't look good. Also I need this in vanila javascript, not jquery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be able to just add a margin or padding to the red section that is the same height as your header or add a transparent div to the top of the red section that is the same height. Lastly, you could calculate the scrollTop and factor in the height of the yellow box.

Comment: @Taysky css is not a good option, I already tried that. Calculating scrollTop would be the best solution, but I don't know how to do that, I am a very begginer in javascript. If you know how to add that part in this script please do if it is not a problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this, it calculates the height of the header and later subtracts it from the scroll position :

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/poqzb33o/)

```
header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar'),
space = header[0].clientHeight;

...

var targetY = -space;
```

---

Update - requested feature in the comment to redefine the offset. For that I've made `targetY` a global variable, it can de updated by executing a function. So in the script where the class gets toggled on scroll, after that happens just add a line with `headerSpace();` and it will recalculate the height. From what I read, the initial class also remains so it should work without any further adjustment.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9974tyyb/)

The inline script on the button was also removed and made into an event listener...

---

Final version - implementation of `requestAnimationFrame` which will make the animation smoother and also be easier on the CPU. The original function is left in place as a fallback for when the feature isn't available. Duration can be set with the variable at the top (with 600ms now matches the 30 steps of 20ms that was set before). Also thought it might be handy to put the header height check inside the button click event handler. So it always recalculates when the user activates the scroll animation (and no need anymore to hook it into the toggling class directly) :

[**Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOyVZd?editors=001)

```
duration = 600
```

Essential code :

```
scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {

    if (modern) {
    var present = Date.now(),
    elapsed = present-initial,
    progress = Math.min(elapsed/duration, 1);
    c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) * progress;
    if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    scroll(c, a, b, i);
    });
    }
    else {
    i++; if (i > 30) return;
    c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
    setTimeout(function() {scroll(c, a, b, i)}, 20);
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, it may appear to be animating quite sudden the first time when the button is clicked but that is because of Codepen. I suspect the focus is on the window with the script in it and not the content itself. Because of this that window has to 'wake up' first, a energy saving aspect of `requestAnimationFrame`. When clicking anywhere else inside the content first, this will disappear. It should also not happen in a live environment. I might send them a message about it...

Comment: Thanks, that works! But tell me can I somehow add also fixed offset? Because when I scroll down my navbar get smaller, and I didn't considered that when asked the question. On scroll it add another class on navbar and add style to that new class to make navbar smaller. And this script is making offset of a primary navbar class. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: No problem, I'll have a good look at it and update the answer later with all tweaks resolved...

Comment: "The inline script on the button was also removed and made into an event listener..."
Is it possible to use the smoother code for scrolling whit onclick="" html function? Whit an inline script as the old demo  http://jsfiddle.net/9974tyyb/

Comment: Sure @Alfonso, that would be a small change that doesn't affect the scrolling function itself. Event listeners are a better practice to use though. http://jsfiddle.net/sjx0c7sz/

Answer (score 0):

Please, find my solution here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjSfP/153/)

```
window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do { //find scroll container
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = -1* document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].offsetHeight;;
        console.log (document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].height);
    do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
        i = i+ 0.125; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 50);
    }
    // start scrolling
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}
```

I have put the put the targetY to be: -1* document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].offsetHeight; This has solved the target issue. as for smooth srolling, I have reduced the movements' increments to be: 0.125.